# how to use yaml-cpp to modify a map node (delete key's value)

Tags: nodes, yaml-cpp

Taking this yaml node for example:

```
- flow:
    - do:
        ? command:
            - command1: command
            - command2: command
            - command3: command
          name: nameblock
          descr: descrblock
        : block_1
```

For the value "block_1", the key is a map node. How can I use yaml-cpp to delete the most inner value "block_1", so that the whole node becomes:

```
- flow:
    - do:
          command:
            - command1: command
            - command2: command
            - command3: command
          name: nameblock
          descr: descrblock
```

Any suggestion? Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to reassign the whole containing node, rather than delete anything. For example:

```
YAML::Node root = YAML::LoadFile("test.yaml");

// this is now the value of the "do" node
// explanation of each value:
// root[0]  - zeroth entry in the top-level sequence
// ["flow"] - value for the key "flow"
// [0]      - zeroth entry in the resulting sequence
// ["do"]   - value for the key "do"
YAML::Node node = root[0]["flow"][0]["do"];

// we're assuming there's only one entry in the map
// if you want a particular one, you can hunt for it
assert(node.size() == 1);  

// this is the key of the first key/value pair
YAML::Node key = node.begin()->first;

// update the whole key/value pair to be just the key
node = key;
```